# Can't import a class from another python file

Tags: python

I searched on internet but I still don't understand why my code doesn't work. I have a Python file called Era.py, in this file I have this class:

```python
class input:

    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username
        close = ["X", "x"]
        print("So, let's start, sweetheart, press X when you want to stop. \n")
        user_input = input("")
        user_input = user_input.upper()
        while user_input not in close:
            user_in = Subject(username, user_input)
            user_input = input("")
        print("Good bye, sweetheart!")
```

And in another Python file, read_from_database.py I have this:

```python
class oldUser:

    def __init__(self, login, password):
        self.login = login
        self.password = password
        results = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" + login + "'" + " AND password = " + "'" + password + "'"
        mycursor.execute(results)
        results = mycursor.fetchall()
        if not results:
            print("User don't exist or wrong login details! \n")
            print(add_to_database)
        else:
            print("Login successfully!")
            from Era import input
            execute = input(login)
```

But when I try to import from Era, input, I have this error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'input' from 'Era'

All files are in the same folder and theoretically it should work, 1 week ago it worked

Comment: try rename your function to _input(), it may be a conflict with `input` function native in Python.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if you have a name collision in defining your class. Specifically, at the line `user_input = input("")`. Try running `python Era.py` and see if your script even runs.

Comment: Following-up on @AngeloMendes' comment, try renaming your class `Input`.

Comment: @davedwards An `__init__.py` file is not necessary in this case, as long as both files are in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are overriding the built-in `input` function of Python, while still trying to use it.
You can see this in the `input` class of your `Era.py` file.
This class attempts to use the built-in `input` function for collecting `user_input`.
Because of this, attempting to `from Era import input` will occasionally fail, as Python gets confused about what to do.
Bottom line here is that you should never override any built-in functions (especially if you need them as well) unless you know what you are doing.

To add to this, it is common in Python that class names start with a capital letter and use no underscores, while functions and modules (like `Era` here) have only lowercase letters and underscores.

So, change your code to the following:

```py
# era.py
class Input:
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username
        close = ["X", "x"]
        print("So, let's start, sweetheart, press X when you want to stop. \n")
        user_input = input("")
        user_input = user_input.upper()
        while user_input not in close:
            user_in = Subject(username, user_input)
            user_input = input("")
        print("Good bye, sweetheart!")
```

```py
# read_from_database.py
from era import Input

class OldUser:
    def __init__(self, login, password):
        self.login = login
        self.password = password
        results = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" + login + "'" + " AND password = " + "'" + password + "'"
        mycursor.execute(results)
        results = mycursor.fetchall()
        if not results:
            print("User don't exist or wrong login details! \n")
            print(add_to_database)
        else:
            print("Login successfully!")
            execute = Input(login)
```

You also may want to have a look at your `Input` class, as it can be simplified in several ways.

Comment: Did you also change the filename from `Era.py` to `era.py`?